# Dynamic bit representation of python integers?

Tags: python, bit-manipulation

I was looking at bit-manipulation in python.  I noticed that every time I shifted over the bit representation of an integer it continued to work.  How does this work in python and is it safe?  Will this cause a memory overflow at some point?  Here's a sample test I ran to see if I could keep going.  https://repl.it/KPp2/0

```
    value = (1 << 20)
    print "20 bits", value, value.bit_length()
    value <<= 12
    print "32 bits", value, value.bit_length()
    value <<= 12
    print "44 bits", value, value.bit_length()
    value <<= 20
    print "64 bits", value, value.bit_length()
    value <<= 8
    print "72 bits", value, value.bit_length()
    value <<= 56
    print "128 bits", value, value.bit_length()
    value <<= 128
    print "256 bits", value, value.bit_length()
    value <<= 256
    print "512 bits", value, value.bit_length()
    value <<= 512
    print "1024 bits", value, value.bit_length()
```

Comment: "Will this cause a memory overflow at some point?" - sure, if you try to use an integer several gigabytes long.

Comment: I guess the better question is if it'll start overwriting other data / if it protects against it.

Comment: It's not going to start overwriting arbitrary memory to the left of your integer; it builds new integer objects.

Comment: How's it represented.  Multiple uint32_t's working together?